# Parse Data received from Pyserial read into string

Tags: python, python-2.7, serial-port, byte, pyserial

I am reading data from a serial port using python (pyserial) I am able to read the data but when I try using it, it seems like this `$*%\xff\x06$*%\xff\x02` referred to few resources on stack overflow and found that it needs to be decoded, I tried decoding it to ascii using `processed = (binascii.b2a_qp(raw))`using the `binascii` library but received the following output `$*%=FF=00$*%=FF=08` I  have also tried decoding the same to UTF-8 but still no success. Any suggestions about how to process the input received from the `read()` function. I also tried using the `readline()` but the program then goes blank or infinite execution seems there is no EOL marker in the serial output.
The Demo Code snip is as follows :

```
with serial.Serial('/dev/cu.usbserial-Device',9600) as ser:
    ser.flushInput()
    ser.flushOutput()
    ser.write('S')
    inputVal=[]
    while(len(inputVal)<10000):
        val = ser.read(10)
        inputVal.append(binascii.b2a_qp(val))
```

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please show the code you're using? I mean a complete snippet that can be run standalone. It would help if you also mention what device is on the other side of your serial line. You seem to be having noise on the bus or your settings are messed up otherwise you would see raw bytes as: `\xHH\xHH...` with HH are HEX numbers. So maybe a word on how you're connecting the lines might help.

Comment: @MarcosG. Question Updated

Comment: Can you try to read data from a terminal utility (something like RealTerm for Windows or minicom for Linux, sorry I don't know any of those for Mac, but they should be easy to find). It might also be the device on the other side of the serial port, where are you receiving the data from?

Comment: I am getting $*% followed by some numbers.

Comment: OK, but what would you expect to get? do you have a protocol?

Comment: yes I need the same numbers I am getting via serial terminals. ie. I need the same output as the serial terminals give.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/195181/discussion-between-marcos-g-and-oshoparth).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to encode whilst writing to the serial port.

```
ser.write(str.encode('S\r')
```

While, to read, I would use something like

```
a = ser.readline()
b = v.rstrip()
c = b.decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: it strips trailing and EOL characters. I use it as default since,in my case, I need to use EOL when using serial communication .